# vertical column headers in microsoft reports possible?

Tags: reporting-services, reporting

I have a report that can have 20+ columns I need to be able to generate column header text vertically such as:

```
x | x |
x | x | 
x | x |
x | x |
------
1 | 4 |
8 | 4 |
```

and so on, is there a way to do this in the .rdlc? Or is the use of images my only option?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set the WritingMode property to tb-rl

Answer (score 0):

For Reporting Services 2005, see this article:

https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/reporting-services/ten-common-sql-server-reporting-services-challenges-and-solutions/#hr6

Comment: Note that link-only answers are discouraged, references tend to get stale over time. Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.